# git file history browsing

Tags: git, ubuntu-10.04

is there a way to browse the history versions (rather than the plain diff) in a git repo?
i'm looking something like what you would expect from tortoiseSvn log/diff browser but for ubuntu. I don't want to see the diffs directly but rather the whole file with the version in its original context, with a highlight showing diffs from previous version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gitg does this, available through the repositories. There are other git visualizers but I don't know about them.

For gitg choose the commit in the branch, and then the 'tree' tab (next to 'details', which show the difference).

Answer (score 1):

There is tortoiseGit. I would recommend on not cloning as much as I did with tortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0):

to follow up with koen, there is also `gitk`, also known as `git-gui`, which is the "official" gui git browser, and shows diffs on a per-commit basis, and commits in a tree, as well as `qgit`, which is quite similar, but with a qt interface.

to launch `gitk`, just type `gitk ~/path/to/my/AWESOMEPROJECTOFAWESOME` and browse away!

You may have to `sudo apt-get install gitk` depending on how you installed `git`.

Comment: He's coming from the Windows world most likely and hence gitk is installed by default with msysgit.

Comment: with gitk you don't get the side-by-side diff

Comment: gitk allows you to adjust the lines of context you see in any commit and flip between the original and new versions in any commit. just another tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [gitup](http://gitup.co/) for the last few months, and aside from a few graphical quirks, it's been quite a pleasure to work with.